# Mouse behaviour in insider Win 10 16199

Tags: mouse

I have two monitors, same resolution but slightly different sizes. They are setup as separate not spanned. Moving the mouse from one screen to the other is erratic. The cursor often vanishes. Moving it very slowly, I can see that the vertical position of the cursor doesn't match across the screens.

This is annoying. Is there any setting I can set to improve this please

Comment: Does this behavior happen on the stable channel build?

Comment: I wouldn't know, I'm an Insider.

Comment: That was a hint that you should test it so you can rule out if the beheavior is caused by the beta build or existsi in the stable build

Comment: I understood that but it isn't practical on my single system. Thanks anyway.